Create boundary box without overlapping
Is there a way to create a tight boundary box around these shapes without creating a shape which will overlap other shapes which aren't the selected feature.

Creating a convex hull will create these shapes but they overlap, is there any potential way for them to not overlap yet cover the selected features?

Buffer by the maximum distance between your rows of features, then debuffer. The result isn't straight, but wont overlap with other buffers.

Also, look up concave hull algorithms, or α-shape/hull!
